# I need sum values from one column with python but the final values are less when I sum in excel, why this happen? how can I solve?

Tags: python, excel

I need sum values from one column with python but the final values are less when I sum in excel, why this happen? How can I solve?

I donwload the data is from here: https://www12.senado.leg.br/orcamento/sigabrasil

In excel = 65,835,344,295.19

In python = 62674107049

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_replace
from pyspark.sql.types import DecimalType

relatorio_2022 = "file.url"

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CSVRead").getOrCreate()

df_2022 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").option("header", "true").csv(relatorio_2022)

df_2022 = df_2022.withColumn("Pago", regexp_replace(col("Pago"), "\\.", "").cast("string"))
df_2022 = df_2022.withColumn("Pago", regexp_replace(col("Pago"), ",", ".").cast(DecimalType()))

soma_pago = df_2022.selectExpr("sum(pago)").collect()[0][0]

print("A soma da coluna 'pago' é:", soma_pago)
```